# Own server with NodeJs and error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: node.js, http, cors

I made my own http server with NodeJS (but without Express e.g),and i got popular problem "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.103:8080' is therefore not allowed access" while getting file from url with XHR.
My http-server file looks like:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env node
>
> 'use strict';
>
> var colors     = require('colors/safe'),
>     os         = require('os'),
>     httpServer = require('../lib/http-server'),
>     portfinder = require('portfinder'),
>     opener     = require('opener'),
>     argv       = require('optimist')
>       .boolean('cors')
>       .argv;
>
> var ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
>
> if (argv.h || argv.help) {
>   console.log([
>     'usage: http-server [path] [options]',
>     '',
>     'options:',
>     '  -p           Port to use [8080]',
>     '  -a           Address to use [0.0.0.0]',
>     '  -d           Show directory listings [true]',
>     '  -i           Display autoIndex [true]',
>     '  -g --gzip    Serve gzip files when possible [false]',
>     '  -e --ext     Default file extension if none supplied [none]',
>     '  -s --silent  Suppress log messages from output',
>     '  --cors[=headers]   Enable CORS via the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header',
>     '                     Optionally provide CORS headers list separated by commas',
>     '  -o [path]    Open browser window after starting the server',
>     '  -c           Cache time (max-age) in seconds [3600], e.g. -c10 for 10 seconds.',
>     '               To disable caching, use -c-1.',
>     '  -U --utc     Use UTC time format in log messages.',
>     '',
>     '  -P --proxy   Fallback proxy if the request cannot be resolved. e.g.: http://someurl.com',
>     '',
>     '  -S --ssl     Enable https.',
>     '  -C --cert    Path to ssl cert file (default: cert.pem).',
>     '  -K --key     Path to ssl key file (default: key.pem).',
>     '',
>     '  -r --robots  Respond to /robots.txt [User-agent: *\\nDisallow: /]',
>     '  --no-dotfiles  Do not show dotfiles',
>     '  -h --help    Print this list and exit.'
>   ].join('\n'));
>   process.exit();
> }
>
> var port = argv.p || parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10),
>     host = argv.a || '0.0.0.0',
>     ssl = !!argv.S || !!argv.ssl,
>     proxy = argv.P || argv.proxy,
>     utc = argv.U || argv.utc,
>     logger;
>
> if (!argv.s && !argv.silent) {
>   logger = {
>     info: console.log,
>     request: function (req, res, error) {
>       var date = utc ? new Date().toUTCString() : new Date();
>       if (error) {
>         logger.info(
>           '[%s] "%s %s" Error (%s): "%s"',
>           date, colors.red(req.method), colors.red(req.url),
>           colors.red(error.status.toString()), colors.red(error.message)
>         );
>       }
>       else {
>         logger.info(
>           '[%s] "%s %s" "%s"',
>           date, colors.cyan(req.method), colors.cyan(req.url),
>           req.headers['user-agent']
>         );
>       }
>     }
>   };
> }
> else if (colors) {
>   logger = {
>     info: function () {},
>     request: function () {}
>   };
> }
>
> if (!port) {
>   portfinder.basePort = 8080;
>   portfinder.getPort(function (err, port) {
>     if (err) { throw err; }
>     listen(port);
>   });
> }
> else {
>   listen(port);
> }
>
> function listen(port) {
>   var options = {
>     root: argv._[0],
>     cache: argv.c,
>     showDir: argv.d,
>     autoIndex: argv.i,
>     gzip: argv.g || argv.gzip,
>     robots: argv.r || argv.robots,
>     ext: argv.e || argv.ext,
>     logFn: logger.request,
>     proxy: proxy,
>     showDotfiles: argv.dotfiles
>   };
>
>   if (argv.cors) {
>     options.cors = true;
>     if (typeof argv.cors === 'string') {
>       options.corsHeaders = argv.cors;
>     }
>   }
>
>   if (ssl) {
>     options.https = {
>       cert: argv.C || argv.cert || 'cert.pem',
>       key: argv.K || argv.key || 'key.pem'
>     };
>   }
>
>   var server = httpServer.createServer(options);
>   server.listen(port, host, function () {
>     var canonicalHost = host === '0.0.0.0' ? '127.0.0.1' : host,
>         protocol      = ssl ? 'https://' : 'http://';
>
>     logger.info([colors.yellow('Starting up http-server, serving '),
>       colors.cyan(server.root),
>       ssl ? (colors.yellow(' through') + colors.cyan(' https')) : '',
>       colors.yellow('\nAvailable on:')
>     ].join(''));
>
>     if (argv.a && host !== '0.0.0.0') {
>       logger.info(('  ' + protocol + canonicalHost + ':' + colors.green(port.toString())));
>     }
>     else {
>       Object.keys(ifaces).forEach(function (dev) {
>         ifaces[dev].forEach(function (details) {
>           if (details.family === 'IPv4') {
>             logger.info(('  ' + protocol + details.address + ':' + colors.green(port.toString())));
>           }
>         });
>       });
>     }
>
>     if (typeof proxy === 'string') {
>       logger.info('Unhandled requests will be served from: ' + proxy);
>     }
>
>     logger.info('Hit CTRL-C to stop the server');
>     if (argv.o) {
>       opener(
>         protocol + canonicalHost + ':' + port,
>         { command: argv.o !== true ? argv.o : null }
>       );
>     }
>   });
> }
>
> if (process.platform === 'win32') {
>   require('readline').createInterface({
>     input: process.stdin,
>     output: process.stdout
>   }).on('SIGINT', function () {
>     process.emit('SIGINT');
>   });
> }
>
> process.on('SIGINT', function () {
>   logger.info(colors.red('http-server stopped.'));
>   process.exit();
> });
>
> process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
>   logger.info(colors.red('http-server stopped.'));
>   process.exit();
> });
> ```

The best solution for me will be to add some smart statement in my Javascript file, but in extremis I will modify my httpserver file.

> ```
>   var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
>     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
>     xhr.open('GET', url, true);
>      xhr.responseType = 'json';
>     xhr.onload = function() {
>       var status = xhr.status;
>       if (status === 200) {
>         callback(null, xhr.response);
>       } else {
>         callback(status, xhr.response);
>       }
>     };
>     xhr.send();
> };
>
> app_firebase.storage().ref('X.json').getDownloadURL().then(function
> ```
>
> (url) {
>         getJSON(url,
>         function(err, data) {
>           console.log("fg");
>           if (err !== null) {
>             alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
>           } else {
>             console.log(data);
>           }
>         });
>       });

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue. You're probably calling the server from another "origin" (if even port or protocol differ, the origins are considered different). You need to add the origin you are making calls from to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header of responses. Check the linked docs for a more in-depth discussion and what needs to happen.